# Markdown in user comments (with proper sanitize and Youtube videos)

Tags: c#, markdown, html-sanitizing

I stucked on decision how I should proceed with Markdown processing and Html sanitize. I have this user requirements for comments/articles:

1. Users should be able to use Markdown syntax
2. Users should be able to post youtube videos / yandex.music audios
3. Of course, users shoudn't be trusted and their input should be validated for all kind of attacks
4. In particular, I don't want to allow users to submit arbitrary iframes

I even submitted fix to [`markdig`](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig) library to support yandex.music in media extensions. But now I'm stuck. There is my explored options:

## Markdig, then [HtmlRuleSanitizer](https://github.com/Vereyon/HtmlRuleSanitizer)

I configured `Markdig` to convert youtube/yandex.music to iframes, than sanitize with `HtmlRuleSanitizer`. `HtmlRuleSanitizer` doesn't have option to allow iframe only for whitelisted domains — so it either will strip out `youtube.com`, or will allow `evilsite.com`. I submitted [suggestion](https://github.com/Vereyon/HtmlRuleSanitizer/issues/19) but doesn't receive any answer.

## HtmlRuleSanitizer, then Markdig

As far as I can understand, that will allow all kinds of XSS attacks — because Markdown-to-Html transform is [inherently unsafe](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Markdown%27s-XSS-Vulnerability-(and-how-to-mitigate-it)#mixed-htmlmarkdown-xss-attack).

## Html-escape everything, then Markdig.

According to same article, that's not safe also.

## Markdig, then [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer)

This sanitizer has appropriate hooks (post-process node), but I'm worried about support of this library, and especially of main dependency - AngleSharp support (it has active reproducibles crashes, and seems to be in active development w/o providing stable API, so HtmlSanitizer seems to have hard time to keep on).

So, any suggestions how I could achieve this goal? I refuse to believe that I'm only one with this issue, and I do hope is **should** be solvable with existing libraries in .net. I'm ready to contribute some feature upstream, if required, but I am not ready to for forking anything. :-)

Comment: You might want to read [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/) which was written by Michel Fortin, the long-time developer of PHP Markdown. While he specifically discusses the PHP library, the principles apply to any Markdown implementation and should help you make your decision.

Comment: @Waylan thanks for nice article, but that's exactly why I ditched option 2 and 3, and I've linked similar article in my quedtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by additions to [HtmlRuleSanitizer](https://github.com/Vereyon/HtmlRuleSanitizer/), specifically by addition of `IHtmlAttributeSanitizer` interface and `SanitizeAttributes` method.

See example here https://github.com/leotsarev/joinrpg-net/blob/88df35fedc5cee73067e9fec9e850cb02826c576/src/JoinRpg.Markdown/HtmlSanitizers.cs#L45